# How to check whether a map is null or not in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I had a map of map of an array and I would like to assign a value if it is null, I tried this code but I didn't get it working

```
    child: Text(
      '${report?.subjects[subject][topic.id]?.length ?? 0} / ${topic?.quizSets?.length ?? 0} Quizzes',
    ),
```

Comment: adding your map data is more helpful ! You can check map==null for null values and map.isEmpty to check for values !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much syntax sugar you can use here to check for `null` since you can't use the dot notation because you need to dynamically retrieve the child properties of your map.

So the only approach would be:

```dart
Text('${report?.subjects[subject][topic.id] != null ? report?.subjects[subject][topic.id].length : 0} / ${topic?.quizSets?.length ?? 0} Quizzes')
```

Note (OT):
This is very hard to read I will rather move this 2 items in 2 separate utility functions such as:

```dart
Text('${_getTopicLength(report) / ${_getQuizSetsLength(topic)} Quizzes')
```